# Disable private key protection

Tags: certificate, biztalk, self-signed, biztalk-2016

When using a self-signed Certificate for signing outgoing AS2 messages with BizTalk I get an error

> The MIME encoder failed to sign the message because the certificate has private key protection turned on ..."

with a suggestion

> please disable private key protection to allow BizTalk to use a certificate for signing.

How do I disable private key protection?

Using Windows Server 2012 R2 and BizTalk Server 2016.

Self-signed certificate created with Powershell New-SelfSignedCertificate.

Comment: Are you sending payload messages (via BizTalk process) or an MDN (as a response via the IIS/w3p.exe process)?

Comment: I'm trying to send an MDN.

Comment: I think this happens if you have/leave the password required setting when installing the Certificate.  Remove and re-add the Cert making sure to leave this option unchecked.

Comment: In the application pool settings of the application pool you are using, make sure you have the 'Load User Profile' setting set to 'True'.

Comment: When using Powershell New-SelfSignedCertificate to create a self-signed certificate a password is mandatory. Also, when installing the certificate there is no option to disable the private key protection.

Comment: My problem is when trying to send an MDN. I don't think IIS is involved when sending. Anyhow, I tried with the Load User Profile set to True, but with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and none of the offered solutions (loading user profile, not selecting strong private key protection in import) worked. I finally solved it when I encountered this old link: http://www.semaphoremd.com/2014/05/23/cryptographic-provider-for-digital-certificate-used-by-as2-in-biztalk. Basically the problem is that Biztalk 2016 still relies on ancient .NET 3.5, which lacks support for KSP. Check the certificate:

```
certutil -p <password> cert.pfx
```

If it says `Provider = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider` then Biztalk will fail and complain about private key protection. Fix it with openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my-original-cert.pfx -out temp.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem -out my-fixed-cert.pfx
```

Import `my-fixed-cert.pfx` to the personal certificate store (and if self-signed also import as CA key). Update Biztalk to use the updated certificate and hopefully the problem should be solved.

EDIT:

If you are starting from scratch, specify the old provider instead:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing the private key, you need to un-tick this option: 
[image]

Comment: This may be greyed out by GPO as done here at work.